# HikariPoolInitializationException: Failed to initialize pool: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, jpa, hikaricp

I am seeing the above error when I am trying to access MySQL database in my local from Spring boot application.

The configuration and properties files are as follows.

**application.properties**

````
```spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sample_db
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=Password123 
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update```
````

This is working fine if I use

````
```spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sample_db?user=root&password=Password123```
````

**DatabaseRepositoryConfig.java**

````
    @Configuration
    @EnableTransactionManagement
    public class DatabaseRepositoryConfig {
    
    @Value("${spring.datasource.driver-class-name}")
        private String driverClass;
    
        @Value("${spring.datasource.url}")
        private String jdbcUrl;
    
         @Value("${spring.datasource.username}")
        private String jdbcUserName;
        
         @Value("${spring.datasource.password}")
         private String jdbcPassword;
    
        @Bean
        public DataSource dataSource() {
            LOG.info("Repository Config ");
            HikariConfig dataSourceConfig = new HikariConfig();
            dataSourceConfig.setDriverClassName(driverClass);
            dataSourceConfig.setJdbcUrl(jdbcUrl);
            dataSourceConfig.setUsername(jdbcUserName);
            dataSourceConfig.setPassword(jdbcPassword);
            return new HikariDataSource(dataSourceConfig);
        }
    
        @Bean
        public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() {
    
            HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
            vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);
            LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
            factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
            factory.setPackagesToScan("com.project.db.entities");
            factory.setDataSource(dataSource());
            factory.afterPropertiesSet();
            return factory.getObject();
        }
    
        @Bean
        public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
            return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
        } ```

**Error:**
Caused by: com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolInitializationException: Failed to initialize pool: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

I tried accessing mySQL from command line and I am able to login as root with the same password. Please let me know what properties are causing this issue?
````

Comment: I hope you are not trying with commented ( # ) lines as it is visible in your example.

Comment: Hi @Aditya T. sorry. I have not tried with the commented code. I forgot to remove the comments when posting the questions.

Comment: What mysql version you are using?